# how to get proper binary string data with XHR without original mime type loss

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, mime-types

When I'm trying to just get data as binary string all `128+` characters have `65533` code. It can be walked around by overriding headers with `text/plain ; charset=x-user-defined`, but then I'm not able to read original mime type. Is there any way to extract original mime or get proper data without overriding headers?

Comment: data comes from foreign source and is unknown. In worst case original mime may be incorrect that's why I need to have both information to properly determine file type

Answer (score 1):

65533 is U+FFFD, the Unicode replacement character.  It seems that somewhere along the way (probably in the XHR), your data is being converted to Unicode incorrectly.  Check the response to make sure it contains the proper data and has a Content-Type header specifying the right charset.  If everything coming from the server checks out but you're still having trouble, you might try another [well documented approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

Comment: the point is it's general file type detector - I'm getting cors data using proxy then detecting type by first few bytes (magic number) then handle content somehow depending on data type. Goal is to make user able to just "open" any url - flash/video/audio/image/pdf. So that I'm detecting by magic number, then by mime, then by extension

Comment: I could just make 2 requests - one with head only, another one with content but well... It comes with additional bandwidth load which is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: as far as I know binary string is only way to get partial data with xhr

Comment: hmm. Considering that data on foreign server may have bad mime I guess 2 requests really are the only way as mime set by server may always corrupt data